# $("#element").va() возвращает пустую строку, но если это прописать в консоли(ctrl+shift+i), то возвращается правильное значение

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

```
<input id="ttl"></input>
<textarea rows="68" maxlength="68" wrap="soft" id="md"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var title = $("#ttl").val();
        body = $("#md").val();
    console.log([title, body]); // --> ['', '']
</script>
```

---

Все id уникальны, но всегда возвращаются пустые строки, пробовал без jquery, всё тоже самое: в переменных пустые строки, но попытаться узнать значение через консоль, то всё работает.

---

[image: скриншот консоли]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно будут возвращаться пустые значения, у вас же ничего не введено на момент выполнения кода.

---

И кстати, инпут пишется не так:

```
<input id="ttl"></input>
                ^^^^^^^^ не нужно
```

а так

```
<input id="ttl" type="text">
                 ^^^^^^^^^ желательно
```